# SAP BO : web intelligence : rowcount

Tags: business-objects

I have created a report in SAP BO Web Intelligence, I have input controls where users can select
permission, I need to know how many rows are there in the report after choosing the condition.

I have tried count and row number, but it just gives me total rows, not the rows based on input control.

please help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the **Dependencies** of your input control and specify to which elements you want it to apply.

[image]

Noel

Comment: it worked , i was using wrong column in count, thanks for your reply